# Selenium TimeoutException with Flask and Python

Tags: python, selenium, flask, timeoutexception

This is what my code looks like

```
@app.route("/Committ", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def Committ():
  ......
  if(......):
    #do sthg
    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.priavtebrowsing.autostart",True)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = firefox_profile)
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
    assert "Instagram" in driver.title
    ......
    driver.close()
```

After running the code above for a number a time usually at the 2nd or third time I get the following error:
[image: condtion 1]

I try add a try and except to avoid this from happening but it didn't rly workout.

[image: UnboundLocalError]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to be a minor issue to cause the whole thing to fall apart, where when flask navigates to a page is like calling a function, everything would goes away when it leaves the page. However selenium always makes internal changes, thus I didn't properly closed the driver when I leave the function causing confusion when the function got called again!

This is what I originally have:

```
...do sthg...
return redirect(url_for('home'))
driver.close()
```

A simple fix would be

```
...do sthg...
driver.close()
return redirect(url_for('home'))
```